# How can I save Ransack searches to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm trying to save Ransack searches to the database. I believe I should be able to just store the `params[:q]` value, then append that to the search URL when I want to recall the search. I don't know how to save the `params[:q]` value, though.

The URL that Ransack creates is something like this:

```
http://site.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bone%5D=something&q%5Btwo%5D=&q%5Bthree%5D=&q%5Blow_number%5D=0&q%5Bhigh_number%5D=300000&q%5Bfour%5D=&commit=Search
```

My route to the action that will save the search is:

```
match 'users/:id/saved_search_add' => 'users#saved_search_add', :as => :saved_search_add
```

If I use this code in the view:

```
<%= link_to('Save Search', saved_search_add_path(current_user, :q => params[:q])) %>
```

With this code in the controller:

```
  def saved_search_add
    @saved_search = Search.create(:query => params[:q].to_hash, :user_id => @user.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @saved_search.save
        format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Then the data stored is:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
one: ''
two: ''
three: ''
low_number: '0'
high_number: '300000'
four: ''
```

So, I need to somehow format the data as it's going into the database (and perhaps also as it's coming out?)... I've read something about serializing it, but I haven't had much luck getting that to work.

How can I get `params[:q]` into my database, to be used later to recreate the full search URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up just using `request.fullpath` instead of `params[:q]`.

The code that saves the query to the database is in the `Users` Controller:

```
def saved_search_add
  @saved_search = Search.create(:query => params[:q], :user_id => current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @saved_search.save
      format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
    end
  end
end
```

The code I use in my View to send the search query to the `Users` Controller is:

```
<%= link_to('Save Search', saved_search_add_path(current_user, :q => request.fullpath)) %>
```

The query value is stored in the database as:

```
/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bone%5D=something&q%5Btwo%5D=&q%5Bthree%5D=&q%5Blow_number%5D=0&q%5Bhigh_number%5D=300000&q%5Bfour%5D=&commit=Search
```

I create the link to that saved search in the View with:

```
<%= link_to "Saved Search", search.query %>
```