# Rails 4 savable search

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-4

I looked around today for a best practice / recipe for a savable search done the Rails way. Maybe something where the target model is polymorphic, and the searchable fields dynamic, maybe defined in a hash or something? Anyone have any good links, gists or recipes?

Comment: Good question! I currently have the same problem - I use a SavedSearch model with lots of `belongs_to` associations but I think there should be a better way... I hope someone else has a good suggestion.

Comment: For others looking to implement something, this might be useful https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack then save the whole query as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14553363/484689